# MongoDB backup from a mounted disk

Tags: linux, mongodb, ssh

I was running MongoDB from a Google Compute Engine Instance. Due to some changes in the SSH configurations, i am now unable to SSH into the instance. Hence, i am also unable to login to MongoDB from a client because SSH is not working.

I want to copy the MongoDB database from this instance and start a new instance and copy the database to it.

I cannot SSH into the old instance so i mounted it's disk to another instance and opened /var/lib/mongodb folder. In this folder there are .wt files, journal folder and some other files.

I copied this mongodb folder to the new instance's mongodb folder. Now when i try to run mongodb server it gives me an error.

Which files/folders should i copy from the disk to complete backup the database?

Also, can i start mongodb server from the mounted disk and then run mongodump to create a backup?

**Update: Error after copying database**

MongoDB shell version v3.4.2

connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017

2017-03-23T06:18:19.422+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused

2017-03-23T06:18:19.487+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13

@(connect):1:6

exception: connect failed

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Hi gview. i have updated the question with the error.

Comment: No that is the error trying to run the client.  Of course you can't connect to mongo when it isn't running.  You need to look in the mongodb server logs to see what is happening when your mongod is starting up.

Comment: How did you resolve this?